# Pass input into onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input that looks like this

```
<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" value="" class="my_files" name="my_files[0]"></input>
```

and when the value changes it calls this function

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {  
        alert(e.type)           
        $('.my_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('.vehicle_preview').delay(700).slideDown('slow');
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

The purpose of all this is to generate a preview image when one is uploaded.  The problem is that I can't target the my_preview I want because I am not passing anything I can use in to find the closest one .... any suggestions? I should add that the complication comes from the fact that there are multiple uploads possible.

Comment: You are dealing with a bigger kettle of fish here. You should do some googling of preview images before upload before attacking this. The file someone is uploading is local to them so you can't preview it as the client doesn't have permission to the local filesystem.

Comment: You most certainly can as this code works

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you saying that there are multiple elements with the class `my_preview` on the page, and you want to target a specific one? Or are you saying that you can't find the right image file to set the element with class `my_preview`'s `src` attr to? Or something completely different?

Comment: I'm saying there are multiple my_previews which display the preview for my_files so I need to target the right one.